# list.Sort ArgumentException error: IComparer doesn't not return 0(null)

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

i have the following problem and I cannot figure out where it comes from. I would appreciate help very much.

The code:

```
List<Point> lst = new List<Point>();
lst.Add(new Point(0, -2));
lst.Add(new Point(-1, -2));

lst.Sort(delegate (Point x,Point y)
{
    if (x.X == 0)
        return -1;
    else if (y.X == 0)
        return 1;
    else
    {
        double retVal1 = x.Y * 1.0 / -x.X;
        double retVal2 = y.Y * 1.0 / -y.X;
        int retVal = -Math.Sign(retVal1 - retVal2);
        return retVal;
    }
});
```

If executed, I recieve an ArgumentException saying that IComparer doesn't not return 0(null). However, it actually cannot return anything else but -1, 0 and 1, or?

Thank you very much for your help!

Ah, btw i'm using .NET 3.5

Comment: It _doesn't_ return 0. Where do you see that it does? Even if the calculations in the `else` block _did_ equate to zero, it is not known.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually the error message says: *IComparer (or the IComparable methods it relies upon) did not return zero when Array.Sort called x. CompareTo(x). x: ''  x's type: 'Point' The IComparer: 'System.Array+FunctorComparer`1[System.Drawing.Point]'*.

You must return 0 if the objects are identical:

```
    lst.Sort(delegate(Point x, Point y) {
        if (x.X == y.X && x.Y == y.Y) { // you are missing this
            return 0;
        }
        if (x.X == 0)
            return -1;
        else if (y.X == 0)
            return 1;
        else {
            double retVal1 = x.Y * 1.0 / -x.X;
            double retVal2 = y.Y * 1.0 / -y.X;
            int retVal = -Math.Sign(retVal1 - retVal2);
            return retVal;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This still violates consistent ordering in the next test, as if Point a is {0, 1} and point b is {0, 2} then calling (a, b) returns -1 meaning a < b but calling (b, a) returns -1 meaning b < a.

Comment: @Jon Hanna: you are right, I just checked the error that occurred with the example, and assumed the rest was correct.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't completely read the Exception-Message. It most likely says that it does not return 0 for the same instance of the object.

Your code is wrong, if the same instance of `Point` or an identical value is passed in, it needs to return `0`. Otherwise he would never know when he's done with sorting and would end up in an endless loop...and we all know that this is an absolute negative performance hit.

Comment: Ah, okay so the Comparer has to be 0 for the same value. Didn't knew that, thanks for the answer! (Actually it's quite logical, but it never occured to me)

Answer (score 0):

As said, a comparer must return 0 for the the same value as identity entails equality (something is always equal to itself) and equality entails equivalence (you *may* order two different things equivalently, but you *must* order two equal things equivalently).

There is a further problem, in that your check for .X being 0 could result in the same items returning inconsistent ordering if they both have .X equal to 0. It's an important rule that a comparison method must always be consistent in that:

If x < y then y > x.

If x < y and y < z then x < z.

Your algorithm breaks the first rule as thus:

Say point a is {0, 3} and point b is {0, 2}

Calling with (a, b) then returns -1 meaning a < b, but calling with (b, a) returns -1 meaning b < a.

Replace the whole thing with:

```
lst.Sort(delegate (Point x,Point y)
{
  return (x.Y * 1.0 / -x.X).CompareTo(y.Y * 1.0 / -y.X);
});
```

(Note that this implicitly returns 0 for equal points - we could add an explicit check if this was a heavier calculation as an optimisation, but it isn't necessary.

Also, is `Point` here `System.Drawing.Point`? If so then this code is now fine, but if it's something else then it's worth noting that the code is fine if `Point` is a struct, but should contain a null check if `Point` is a class.